# Unable to boot Ubuntu after deleting Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a year ago using Wubi, and was dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu until today when I decided to use Ubuntu alone. I used Gparted to delete the Windows partition and then resized the Linux partitions.

Following which, I started getting the "winboot wubildr.mbr missing" error. I booted from the Ubuntu live CD again and ran boot-repair, but am still getting the same or a similar error.

This is my paste: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8902994/

Can someone advise on what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: ehm. If you installed Ubuntu with WUBI it is part of your Windows installation and gets deleted when  you delete windows.

Comment: Damn. So the only thing I can do is reinstall ubuntu, say from a live CD?

Comment: I would advice to boot a live dvd and investigate the disks. If you have anything important on the disks you might be able to restore the partitions if you did nothing to them after deleting with software called "testdisk"

Comment: Boot-Repair shows your wubi install in sda6. Normally those that use wubi do not add partitions for wubi as that is one of its advantages. But you can from live installer mount wubi and backup your data. You can even boot wubi from grub if you really wanted to. If you need help post back. Instructions here assume sda1, yours is sda6. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi crates virtual partitions as image files inside your Windows drive. This is an easy way to install Ubuntu Linux without doing major changes to the drive, but it comes with a lot of draw backs. For example the stability of your Linux file system is always at the mercy of your Windows file system and they are not so good at being stable. And of cause if you delete your Windows you will also delete the Linux that is contained inside.

In general you should not use Wubi. It is deprecated, has a lot of bugs and has not been maintained for a while.

I'm sorry to say, but to solve your problem you will have to reinstall Ubuntu. The best would be to install the latest LTS version (14.04) while booting from an installation media ( Live DVD, USB stick).